# navigation from 2 different pages to the same page both passing parameters

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i want to navigate from 2 different pages p2 and p3 to page p1.
both pages p2 and p3 pass parameters to page p1.
here are the codes of buttons of page p2 and p3

page p2:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem l = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    string s = (string)l.Content;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?ok=" + s, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

page p3:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem l = (ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    string s = (string)l.Content;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?ko=" + s, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

I want to know the code of OnNavigatedTo function in page p1 so that it can receive both parameters and display them in 2 different textblocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your parameters are named differently, not too big a deal to query for each one.

```
string ok = string.Empty;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ok", out ok);

string ko = string.Empty;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ko", out ko);
```